# Adding years to array of dates

Tags: javascript, typescript

if by end of the period person is greater than 18 i want `childEndDate` to be the date of person's date when he/she will become 18 years old.
in my else if statement i am using **date-fns** library to add 18 years to dates i have in my `this.childBirthDate` array. but returned output is wrong: `["1988-01-01T00:00:02.012Z", "1988-01-01T00:00:02.010Z", "2031-11-08T13:24:43.704Z"]` 
output i want returned is: `['2030-02-16T20:00:00.000Z', '2028-05-19T20:00:00.000Z', 2031-11-08T13:24:43.704Z]`

here is my [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/my-angular-starter-ncovfx?file=app/app.component.ts)

```
this.childBirthDate = [
  '2012-02-16T20:00:00.000Z',
  '2010-05-19T20:00:00.000Z',
  '2016-05-19T20:00:00.000Z',
];

//enddate
const endYear = date.getFullYear() + 10;
date.setFullYear(endYear);
this.endDate = date.toISOString();

this.childBirthDate.forEach((element) => {
  const birthYear = element.substring(0, 4);
  this.childbirthYear.push(+birthYear);
});

const periodEndYear = +this.endDate.substring(0, 4);

// calculate child endDate
this.childbirthYear.forEach(element => {
  if (periodEndYear - element < 18) {
    this.childEndDate = this.endDate;
  } else if (periodEndYear - element >= 18) {
      this.childEndDate = addYears(new Date(element), 18).toISOString();
  }
  this.final.push(this.childEndDate);
});
console.log(this.final)

this.personalInfo = {
  personalInfoId: 0,
  underageChildInfo: this.data.underageChildInfo?.map((i, index) => ({
    firstName: i.name,
    endDate: this.final[index],
  })),
};
```

Comment: How does this `addYears` function look like?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mre] in the question itself. The code as is won't run locally. While you're in there, you'll want to add the [date-fns] tag so that experts in that library can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your logic to get the end date is reproducing what you want. However, I think your code may be hard to follow due to all the extra variables.

If you remove the `foreach` loops in favor of some `map` operators, your code will log the dates you are looking to get.

e.g.

```
// in ngOnInit
this.finalDates = this.childBirthDate.map(date => {
      return this.calculateDate(date);
    });

// outputs ["2030-02-16T20:00:00.000Z", "2028-05-19T20:00:00.000Z", "2031-11-08T14:28:01.761Z"]
    console.log(this.finalDates);
```

---

```
// custom method on the class
  calculateDate(date: string): string {
    const periodEndYear = +this.endDate.substring(0, 4);
    const year = parseInt(date.substring(0, 4), 10); // get a number from string

    if (periodEndYear - year < 18) {
      return this.endDate;
    } else if (periodEndYear - year >= 18) {
      return addYears(new Date(date), 18).toISOString();
    }
    return date;
  }
```

here is a fork of your [blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/my-angular-starter-ggrhyj?file=app/app.component.ts)

Comment: hi! thank you so much for your answer! one more question, as you can see i have `personalInfo` object in my code, i am saving dates in `endDate` so i can send it to API, how can i save dates based on your answer?

Comment: Can you just call the `calculateDate` method from the map function when creating the `personalInfo` object? I just put the "finalDates" property in the class as an example.

Comment: thank u  so  much!!